# Custom processing on column in Apache Spark (Java)

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I loaded a JSON document in Spark, roughly, it looks like:

```
root
 |-- datasetid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fields: struct (nullable = true)
...
 |    |-- type_description: string (nullable = true)
```

My DF is turning it into:

```
df = df.withColumn("desc", df.col("fields.type_description"));
```

All fine, but `type_description`'s value looks like: "1 - My description type".

Ideally, I'd like my df to contain only the textual part, e.g. "My description type". I know how to do that, but how can I make it through Spark?

I was hoping some along the line of:

```
df = df.withColumn("desc", df.col("fields.type_description").call(/* some kind of transformation class / method*/));
```

Thanks!

Comment: So what exactly are you looking for? Regexp? Substring?  Could you update the question to reflect that?

Comment: Ideally it could be anything... in this situation, i would manage with a substring and trim (there is never more than 2 digits)... but I have other situations that are more interesting like parsing, concatenation of values between columns, call to joda times, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general Spark provides a broad set of SQL functions which vary from basic string processing utilities, through date / time processing functions, to different statistical summaries. This are part of [`o.a.s.sql.functions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html). In this particular case you probably want something like this:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

df.withColumn("desc",
  regexp_replace(df.col("fields.type_description"), "^[0-9]*\\s*-\\s*", "")
);
```

Generally speaking these functions should be your first choice when working with Spark SQL. There are backed by Catalyst expressions and typically provide codegen utilities. It means you can fully benefit from different Spark SQL optimizations.

Alternative, but less efficient approach, is to implement custom UDF. See for example [Creating a SparkSQL UDF in Java outside of SQLContext](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36248206/1560062)

Comment: Awesome - I saw we could do UDF with Python, but I am really glad we can do that with Java too! Tx!