# How to create a Spark UDF in Java / Kotlin which returns a complex type?

Tags: java, apache-spark, kotlin, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to write an UDF which returns a complex type:

```
private val toPrice = UDF1<String, Map<String, String>> { s ->
    val elements = s.split(" ")
    mapOf("value" to elements[0], "currency" to elements[1])
}


val type = DataTypes.createStructType(listOf(
        DataTypes.createStructField("value", DataTypes.StringType, false),
        DataTypes.createStructField("currency", DataTypes.StringType, false)))
df.sqlContext().udf().register("toPrice", toPrice, type)
```

but any time I use this:

```
df = df.withColumn("price", callUDF("toPrice", col("price")))
```

I get a cryptic error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$28: (string) => struct<value:string,currency:string>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:253)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:830)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: scala.MatchError: {value=138.0, currency=USD} (of class java.util.LinkedHashMap)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:379)
    ... 19 more
```

I tried to use a custom data type:

```
class Price(val value: Double, val currency: String) : Serializable
```

with an UDF which returns that type:

```
private val toPrice = UDF1<String, Price> { s ->
    val elements = s.split(" ")
    Price(elements[0].toDouble(), elements[1])
}
```

but then I get another `MatchError` which complains for the `Price` type.

*How do I properly write an UDF which can return a complex type?*

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR** The function should return an object of class `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`.

Spark provides two main variants of `UDF` definitions.

1. `udf` variants using Scala reflection:

   - `def udf[RT](f: () ⇒ RT)(implicit arg0: TypeTag[RT]): UserDefinedFunction`
   - `def udf[RT, A1](f: (A1) ⇒ RT)(implicit arg0: TypeTag[RT], arg1: TypeTag[A1]): UserDefinedFunction`
   - ...
   - `def udf[RT, A1, A2, ..., A10](f: (A1, A2, ..., A10) ⇒ RT)(implicit arg0: TypeTag[RT], arg1: TypeTag[A1], arg2: TypeTag[A2], ..., arg10: TypeTag[A10])`

   which define

   > Scala closure of ... arguments as user-defined function (UDF). The data types are automatically inferred based on the Scala closure's signature.

   These variants are used without schema with atomics or algebraic data types. For example the function in question would be defined in Scala:

   ```scala
   case class Price(value: Double, currency: String) 

   val df = Seq("1 USD").toDF("price")

   val toPrice = udf((s: String) => scala.util.Try { 
     s split(" ") match {
       case Array(price, currency) => Price(price.toDouble, currency)
     }
   }.toOption)

   df.select(toPrice($"price")).show
   // +----------+
   // |UDF(price)|
   // +----------+
   // |[1.0, USD]|
   // +----------+
   ```

   In this variant return type is automatically encoded.

   Due to it's dependence on reflection this variant is intended primarily for Scala users.
2. `udf` variants providing schema definition (one you use here). The return type for this variant, should be the same as for `Dataset[Row]`:

   - As pointed out in the other answer you can use only the types listed in the [SQL types mapping table](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) (atomic types either boxed or unboxed, `java.sql.Timestamp` / `java.sql.Date`, as well as high level collections).
   - Complex structures (`structs` / `StructTypes`) are expressed using `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`. No mixing with algebraic data types or equivalent is allowed. For example (Scala code)

     ```
     struct<_1:int,_2:struct<_1:string,_2:struct<_1:double,_2:int>>>
     ```

     should be expressed as

     ```
     Row(1, Row("foo", Row(-1.0, 42))))
     ```

     not

     ```
     (1, ("foo", (-1.0, 42))))
     ```

     or any mixed variant, like

     ```
     Row(1, Row("foo", (-1.0, 42))))
     ```

   This variant is provided primarily to ensure Java interoperability.

   In this case (equivalent to the one in question) the definition should be similar to the following one:

   ```scala
   import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
   import org.apache.spark.sql.Row


   val schema = StructType(Seq(
     StructField("value", DoubleType, false),
     StructField("currency", StringType, false)
   ))

   val toPrice = udf((s: String) => scala.util.Try { 
     s split(" ") match {
       case Array(price, currency) => Row(price.toDouble, currency)
     }
   }.getOrElse(null), schema)

   df.select(toPrice($"price")).show
   // +----------+
   // |UDF(price)|
   // +----------+
   // |[1.0, USD]|
   // |      null|
   // +----------+
   ```

   Excluding all the nuances of exception handling (in general `UDFs` should contr ol for `null` input and by convention gracefully handle malformed data) Java equivalent should look more or less like this:

   ```java
   UserDefinedFunction price = udf((String s) -> {
       String[] split = s.split(" ");
       return RowFactory.create(Double.parseDouble(split[0]), split[1]);
   }, DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[]{
       DataTypes.createStructField("value", DataTypes.DoubleType, true),
       DataTypes.createStructField("currency", DataTypes.StringType, true)
   }));
   ```

**Context**:

To give you some context this distinction is reflected in the other parts of the API as well. For example, you can create `DataFrame` from a schema and a sequence of `Rows`:

```
def createDataFrame(rows: List[Row], schema: StructType): DataFrame
```

or using reflection with a sequence of `Products`

```
def createDataFrame[A <: Product](data: Seq[A])(implicit arg0: TypeTag[A]): DataFrame
```

but no mixed variants are supported.

In other words you should provide input that can be encoded using `RowEncoder`.

Of course you wouldn't normally use `udf` for the task like this one:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("price", struct(
  split($"price", " ")(0).cast("double").alias("price"),
  split($"price", " ")(1).alias("currency")
))
```

**Related**:

- [Creating a SparkSQL UDF in Java outside of SQLContext](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36248206)

Answer (score 2):

It simple. Go to [Data Types Reference](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) and find the corresponding type.

In Spark 2.3

- If you declare return type as `StructType` the functions **has to** return `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`.
- If you return `Map<String, String>` function return type should be `MapType` - clearly not what you want.

Comment: I'm not transforming the whole `Row`. I just transform a value in a column like this: `5.0 USD` to a struct like this: `Price(5.0, "USD")`. Please read my question again: I tried `Price` with the proper `StructType` declaration as well. Didn't work either.