# Unable to understand UDFs in Spark and especially in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a new column in Spark Datasets based on another column's value. The other column's value is searched in a json file as a key and the returned its value which is the value to be used for new column.

Here is then code that I tried but it doesn't work and I am not sure how UDF's work as well. How do you add a column in this case using withColumn or udf?

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "true").load("file path");
        Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("json path"));
        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;

        df = df.withColumn("cluster", functions.lit(jo.get(df.col("existing col_name")))));
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Spark UDF in Java / Kotlin which returns a complex type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50949384/how-to-create-a-spark-udf-in-java-kotlin-which-returns-a-complex-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Constantine. I was able to better understand UDFs from your example. Here is my java code:

```
        Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("json path"));
        JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;

        spark.udf().register("getJsonVal", new UDF1<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(String key) {
                return  (String) jo.get(key.substring(0, 5));
            }
        }, DataTypes.StringType);

        df = df.withColumn("cluster", functions.callUDF("getJsonVal", df.col("existing col_name")));
        df.show(); // SHOWS NEW CLUSTER COLUMN
```

Comment: Yup.. This looks fine :) Happy to help

Answer (score 2):

Spark allows you to create custom User Defined Functions(UDFs) using **udf** function.

Following is a scala snippet of how to define a UDF.

```
val obj = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("json path"));
val jo = obj.asInstanceOf[JSONObject];

def getJSONObject(key: String) = {
   jo.get(key)
}
```

Once you have defined your function, you can convert it to a UDF as:

```
 val getObject = udf(getJSONObject _)
```

There are two approaches for using UDF.

1. `df.withColumn("cluster", lit(getObject(col("existing_col_name"))))`
2. If you are using spark sql, you have to register your udf in sqlContext before you use it.

   `spark.sqlContext.udf.register("get_object", getJSONObject _)`

   And then you can use it as

   `spark.sql("select get_object(existing_column) from some_table")`

Out of these, which to use is completely subjective.