# UDF return type for List<UserDefinedClass>

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-dataset

I have the following code, which is supposed to process a `WrappedArray` of `Struct`s (`column_x`) and derive a new column (`new_column`), which is supposed to be an array of a user defined objects (I suppose, that in Spark terminology it is Array of Structs):

```
public Dataset<Row> extractFeature(Dataset<Row> originalDataset) {
        UserDefinedFunction myUDF = functions.udf(extract(), DataTypes.createArrayType(
                  DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[]{
                      DataTypes.createStructField("attr_a", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                      DataTypes.createStructField("attr_b", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                      DataTypes.createStructField("attr_c", DataTypes.StringType, true),
                      DataTypes.createStructField("attr_d", DataTypes.LongType, true)
                  })
    ));

    return originalDataset
            .withColumn("new_column", myUDF.apply(col("column_x")))
}

private class MyClass {
    private String attrA;
    private String attrB;
    private String attrC;
    private Long attrD;
}

private UDF1<WrappedArray<Row>, List<MyClass>> extract() {
     return (structsArr) -> {
         List<Row> structsList = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(structsArr);
         // some logic
         List<MyClass> finalOutput = getFinalOutput(...);
         return finalOutput;
     };
}
```

However, when I execute this code snippet in my program, it returns the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value (com.domain.name.and.so.on.MyClass@6ba3fec1) of the type (com.domain.name.and.so.on.MyClass) cannot be converted to struct

I can not find what I may be doing wrong, since `ArrayType` represents collections and `Struct` seems to represent objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a Spark UDF in Java / Kotlin which returns a complex type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50949384/how-to-create-a-spark-udf-in-java-kotlin-which-returns-a-complex-type)

Comment: @user10938362 thank you! Through your linked question I somehow navigated to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50950778/6124434 and it helped me, since the 1st bullet point says, that I have to return `Row` in case I declare return type as `StructType`. Therefore, I have mapped `List<MyClass>` to `List<Row>` and it works now.

Comment: I am glad to hear that (links are generated automatically, so we have no control over that).

Comment: @user10938362 what do you concretely mean by "links" here? Btw to be clear about my previous comment: the answer which I linked in that comment is from the same thread as you sent. I have not realized that at first.