# UDF to cast a map<bigint,struct<in1:bigint,in2:string>> column to add more fields to inner struct

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a hive table, which when read into spark as `spark.table(<table_name>)` having below structure:

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- info: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: long
 |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- in1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- in2: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to cast the map column to add more fields to the inner struct, e.g. in3,in4
in this example : `map<bigint,struct<in1:bigint,in2:string,in3:decimal(18,5),in4:string>>`
I have tried normal cast but that doesn't work. So I am checking if I can achieve this through a UDF.
I will assign defaults to these new values like 0 for decimal and "" for string.
Below is what is tried and can't get it to work. Can anyone pls suggest how do I achieve this?

```
val origStructType = new StructType().add("in1", LongType, nullable = true).add("in2", StringType, nullable = true)
val newStructType = origStructType.add("in1", LongType, nullable = true).add("in2", StringType, nullable = true).add("in3", DecimalType(18,5), nullable = true).add("in4", StringType, nullable = true)
val newColSchema = MapType(LongType, newStructType)      

val m = Map(101L->(101L,"val2"),102L->(102L,"val3"))
val df = Seq((100L,m)).toDF("id","info")
val typeUDFNewRet = udf((col1: Map[Long,Seq[(Long,String)]]) => {
    col1.mapValues(v => Seq(v(0),v(1),null,"")) //Forced to use null here for another issue
  }, newColSchema)
spark.udf.register("typeUDFNewRet",typeUDFNewRet)
df.registerTempTable("op1")
val df2 = spark.sql("select id, typeUDFNewRet(info) from op1")
scala> val df2 = spark.sql("select id, typeUDFNewRet(info) from op1")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, UDF(info): map<bigint,struct<in1:bigint,in2:string,in1:bigint,in2:string,in3:decimal(18,5),in4:string>>]

scala> df2.show(false)
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to scala.collection.Seq
  at $anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:43)
  at scala.collection.MapLike$MappedValues$$anonfun$iterato
```

I have also tried returning as a Row using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50975592) but that gives a diff issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```scala
 val origStructType = new StructType().add("in1", LongType, nullable = true).add("in2", StringType, nullable = true)
    val newStructType = origStructType.add("in3", DecimalType(18,5), nullable = true).add("in4", StringType, nullable = true)
    val newColSchema = MapType(LongType, newStructType)

    val m = Map(101L->(101L,"val2"),102L->(102L,"val3"))
    val df = Seq((100L,m)).toDF("id","info")
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    val typeUDFNewRet = udf((col1: Map[Long,Row]) => {
      col1.mapValues(r => Row.merge(r, Row(null, ""))) //Forced to use null here for another issue
    }, newColSchema)
    spark.udf.register("typeUDFNewRet",typeUDFNewRet)
    df.registerTempTable("op1")
    val df2 = spark.sql("select id, typeUDFNewRet(info) from op1")

    df2.show(false)
    df2.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---+----------------------------------------------+
      * |id |UDF(info)                                     |
      * +---+----------------------------------------------+
      * |100|[101 -> [101, val2,, ], 102 -> [102, val3,, ]]|
      * +---+----------------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- id: long (nullable = false)
      * |-- UDF(info): map (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- key: long
      * |    |-- value: struct (valueContainsNull = true)
      * |    |    |-- in1: long (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- in2: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- in3: decimal(18,5) (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- in4: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

Comment: Thanks @Somehwar this works good. But if I use a non null/blank decimal value in the UDF, e.g.. `col1.mapValues(r => Row.merge(r, Row(0.001, "hello")))` it gives exception `scala.MatchError: 0.001 (of class java.lang.Double)` . Any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: Well, I could get it to work by using `Decimal(0.001)`. So I am marking as answered. Thanks.

Comment: yes use `new BigDecimal(..)` to represent decimal. Please feel free to upvote + accept if it helps