# Spark binary column split into multiple columns

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm writing a Java application. I have a spark `Dataset<MyObject>` that results in a binary type column:

```
Dataset<MyObject> dataset = sparkSession.createDataset(someRDD, Encoders.javaSerialization(MyObject.class));
dataset.printSchema();

//root
//|-- value: binary (nullable = true)
```

`MyObject` has different (nested) fields, and I want to "explode" them in multiple columns in my Dataset. The new columns also need to be computed from multiple attributes in `MyObject`. As a solution, I could use `.withColumn()` and apply a UDF. Unfortunately, I don't know how to accept a binary type in the UDF and then convert it to `MyObject`. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: Binary is represented as an array of bytes, you can try with `byte[]` as input type for the UDF. And see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50949384/how-to-create-a-spark-udf-in-java-kotlin-which-returns-a-complex-type) for how to return complex type from the UDF.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to blackbishop's suggestion I solved it. Here is the complete solution:

You need to register the UDF:

```
UDFRegistration udfRegistration = sparkSession.sqlContext().udf();
udfRegistration.register("extractSomeLong", extractSomeLong(), DataTypes.LongType);
```

Declare and implement the UDF. The first argument must be byte[] and you need to convert the byte array to your object as indicated:

```
private static UDF1<byte[], Long> extractSomeLong() {
    return (byteArray) -> {
        if (byteArray != null) {
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            MyObject traceWritable = (MyObject) is.readObject();
            return traceWritable.getSomeLong();
        }
        else {
            return -1L;
        }
    };
}
```

And finally it can be used with:

```
Dataset<MyObject> data = sparkSession.createDataset(someRDD, Encoders.javaSerialization(MyObject.class));
Dataset<Row> processedData = data.withColumn( "ID", functions.callUDF( "extractSomeLong", new Column("columnName")))
```

Comment: I think you can return map or struct type if you need to extract more than one field. Better than extracting each one with a specific UDF :)